# Updating a website to a new version of Telerik

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, telerik-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am maintaining a website that use this version of Telerik: 2012.3.1018. With this version I have files with telerik prefix like:

```
-telerik.all.min.js
-telerik.autocomplete.min.js
-telerik.calendar.min.js
...
...
-telerik.window.min.js
```

The business want to update the site to a new version: telerik.ui.for.aspnetmvc.2014.1.528.commercial

I found the css, but I can't find the js files. Are they discontinued? 
I am seeing just kendo.js files and I am missing telerik.js files. Can anyone help me to understand the difference between Telerik's version?

Comment: @Behnam can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC has been discontinued in 2013. The successor product is Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC (ASP.NET MVC wrappers for Kendo UI). Have in mind that those products are not compatible and there are API and behavior changes. There is a migration guide available here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/migration/migrating-from-telerik-extensions-for-aspnet-mvc